# window.opener error on trigger event

Tags: jquery, xml, triggers, reload, window.opener

I'm running this code to try to make a page reload after I closed the current one (that edits values from the one thats supposed to reload):

```
setTimeout( function() {
            window.opener.$('window').('reload');
        window.close();trigger
    }, 1700);
```

And I get this error every time:

---

> XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({length:0, prevObject:{0:({}),
>   context:({}), length:1}, context:({}), selector:"window"})

I really don't understand anything about XML and I don't even understand whats wrong...

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You're trying to reference a property of `window.opener` which is equivalent to the jQuery object. Remove the references to the jQuery methods, as that just provides an alternative technique for selecting the current window, and is irrelevant here.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
}, 1700);
```

Comment: Yep , I've figured it out myself , was post the answer just now hehe. Thanks!